# Automate static lib removal before build to prevent Cocoapods duplicate symbols error

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, cocoapods

I am using [Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org/) along with a workspace that contains both my own static lib, as well as the main project that makes use of the static lib.

The static lib and main app share the same pods.

The problem is that the links created after 'pod install' causes duplicate symbol errors when building the main app.

I've looked into removing the libPods.a static lib from my static lib target via a script build phase, as well as a scheme build pre-action. Neither seem to have desired effect.

Here is my Podfile:

```
workspace 'MyWorkspace.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, '6.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

# POD ACTIONS ----------------------------------------

def import_pods
  pod 'AFNetworking', '1.3.2'
  pod 'AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger', '0.10.0'
  pod 'CorePlot', '1.3'
end

# POD LINKAGE -----------------------------------------

target :'MyStaticLib' do
  xcodeproj 'StaticLib/StaticLib.xcodeproj'
  import_pods

  target :'MyApp' do
    xcodeproj 'MyApp.xcodeproj'
  end  
end
```

And the Ruby script to remove the libPods.a from my static lib:

```
require 'xcodeproj'

project = Xcodeproj::Project.open("StaticLib/StaticLib.xcodeproj")
project.targets.each do |target|
  if target.display_name == 'MyStaticLib'
    target.frameworks_build_phase.files_references.each do |file|
      if file.path == "libPods.a"
        file.build_files.each do |build_file|
          build_file.remove_from_project
          puts "Removed build file from project: #{build_file.display_name}"
        end
        file.remove_from_project
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Wilmar's script is what I used; except it had two problems:

1. project.save was not called to persist the file removal - I just added it as  the last line of the above code
2. I needed this as part of a TeamCity CI build; so I just added this script as a "Custom script" Build Step to run, before even invoking xcodebuild, and that worked.

Thank you